# converting C to Lingo

Tags: lingo

does anyone here knows how to convert this expression below to lingo:

```
for(var channel=1;channel<30;channel+=3)
```

there is already sample below on how to use `for` statement to `repeat with`, my problem is i dont know how to use `channel+=3` in lingo statement since they only provided `channel++`.

```
//Lingo 
on puppetize 
    repeat with channel = 1 to 30 
    _movie.puppetSprite(channel, TRUE) 
    end repeat 
end puppetize 

// Javascript 
function puppetize() 
{ 
    for(var channel=1;channel<30;channel++) 
    { 
    _movie.puppetSprite(channel, true); 
    } 
}
```

hope you could help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the [Lingo reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Director/11.5/UsingScripting/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811d64c1a1b3-7b07.html) says about the repeat keyword having no incrementing syntax, you are indeed adding 1 to channel yourself. But did you try using a more basic syntax `c = c + 1` instead of `c++` or `c += 1`? Also, in Lingo, you would be adding only 2, because the repeat loop is already adding 1 on it's own. Please see below.

```
//Lingo 
on puppetize 
    repeat with channel = 1 to 30 
      _movie.puppetSprite(channel, TRUE) 
      channel = channel + 2   <---------------------my change here.
    end repeat 
end puppetize
```